# Compute number of leaves in binary tree recursively (algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

This algorithm should compute the number of leaves on a binary tree recursively

```
ALGORITHM CountLeaves(T )

//Input: A binary tree T
//Output: The number of leaves in T

if T = ∅ return 0
else return CountLeaves(Left Leef)+ CountLeaves(Right Leef)
```

I am not sure how to edit this so it will accurately count leaves? Also, if you could supply proof of why this fails it would be very helpful as to me, it looks like it should be working

Comment: Probably because you don't do a check for when a node is a leaf.  The first check seems to be a null check.  The else just recursively travels through the tree.  What do you when the node is a leaf?  You are never adding anything up a 0 or another recursive call (which will ultimately lead to a 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifications to your approach: the problem is you are not checking a node is leef or not.

```
ALGORITHM CountLeaves(T )

//Input: A binary tree T
//Output: The number of leaves in T

if T = ∅ return 0
else if(left == null and right == null) return 1 // checks for leef node.
else return CountLeaves(Left Leef)+ CountLeaves(Right Leef)
```

Comment: You should explain why his approach did not work since OP asked

Comment: since he is not checking a node is a leef or not. a node is leef if and only if it has no left and right childs.

Answer (score 1):

You're always going to return zero - you need a case like

```
if(left == null and right == null) return 1 // this is a leaf
```

if you want to be able to get a non-zero count